# Configuring hosts throws error

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

While doing a confim hosts step in Ambari hosts setup, the following error is thrown. Any ideas on how I could resolve it?

```
ERROR 2015-09-18 14:32:43,574 main.py:137 - Ambari agent machine hostname (INLL50901688A.xxx) does not match expected ambari server hostname (inll50901688a.xxx). Aborting registration. Please check hostname, hostname -f and /etc/hosts file to confirm your hostname is setup correctly
', None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ambari does not seem to take hostnames containing alphabets in caps. had to modify /etc/HOSTNAME and /etc/hosts to have hostnames in smaller cases.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the case of the host names does not match. Check that your hoat name case in DNS or hosts file is set consistently with the host names you registered with Ambari.